# Find a link with a particular text

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

Using selenium chrome webdriver I am trying to find a link with the below given xpath.

```
xpath = '//a[contains(text(),"Home")]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

This is how the link is in the source:

```
<span class="yyy">
<a href="xxx", target="_top">
<font>Home</font>
</a>
</span>
```

I just want to find the element, just to identify the page I am in.
But this always returns NoSuchElementException to me. 
What is the right way to find such an element?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `a` element doesn't contain any text at all. It contains a `font` and *that* contains text inside it.

So modify it slightly:

```
//a[font[contains(text(), 'Home')]]
```

(Although why you use "Contains" I'm not sure, you should do an **equals** match to be honest)

Comment: I tried this and I also tried '//a[font[text()="Home"]]'. And I still get the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @deepng Works here. Is it in an IFrame? What browser? Have you tried waiting for the element using a `WebDriverWait`?

Comment: Yes, I too think it might be the iFrame. I will see if I can change the iFrame. I have tried WebDriverWait, but that didn't work.

Comment: @deepng, if it's in an IFrame you will have to 'switch' to it: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame